# How to create add fields button like apple contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c

I creating a contact like app, and i trying to create the add fields button like in the apple contacts app that add additional fields at the top.

I thinking to add a tableview inside the header of the main tableview but with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to add some screen shot if it is hard to explain ?

Comment: In the apple contacts at the beginning you have first name last name and company. At the end you have a cell with a button add fields that let you choose which textfield to add to the top section. I want to create that option

Comment: Its just adding a cell to the tableview...its really easy...,btw, i dont think that add contact screen is tableview, its a scrollview, the whole place u wanted to add cell to is a tableview

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i succeeded.

Add new contact is a tableview. And the top fields are rows in another tableview that located in the header of the main table view.

When you tap add fields you add what you want to the array of the sub table view and do reload in the sub table view.